# "Library not found for ___." Error only for Simulator after updating to Xcode 14.2

Tags: swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

My Project was working fine before updating to Xcode 14.2, but now it is throwing the error "Library not found for ___" for Simulator only

[image]

Comment: How did you import AFNetworking? Maybe update that import ?

Comment: I am using CocoaPods

Comment: It is working fine for iPhone but throwing error for Simulator

Answer (score 0):

Select Open using Rosetta in Xcode's Get Info, It will solve the error

[image]